# CRUD операции в Spring Data JPA и Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

> Spring Data JPA – это не реализация JPA, это абстракция доступа к данным БД.

Не могу понять этого выражения в сфере сравнения с реализацией `JPA` (допустим `Hibernate`).  При использовании `Spring Data JPA`,  для использования `CRUD` операций необходимо наследоваться от интерфейса `CrudRepository`, но без `Hibernate` `Spring Data JPA` самостоятельно работать не может, так как он не умеет трансформировать java объект в сущности. НО! `Hibernate` может и сам выполнять `CRUD` операции.  Итого, вопросы:

1. Зачем использовать Spring Data JPA  (именно CRUD операции), если нам все равно необходимо задействовать HIBERNATE?
2. интерфейс CrudRepository – это просто интерфейс, он наследуется от интерфейса Repository.  Мы его наследуем для реализации CRUD операций. Не пойму, как он работает. Как может наш класс выполнять CRUD операции просто унаследовав интерфейс. Там же нет реализованных методов.

Как я могу пока  ответить на эти вопросы:

1. Разве что для упрощения кода. Так как для использования CRUD операций через Hibernate необходимо больше кода.
2. Пока в голову приходят только мысли, что каким-то  («магическим») образом интерфейс CrudRepository использует стандартные средства Hibernate  для использования CRUD операций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разбираться по порядку.

`JPA` (`Java Persistence API`) - Спецификация, которая объясняет как записывать, читать и управлять данными, которые представленны в виде `Java` объектов в реляционных базах данных.

`Hibernate` - Предоставляет одну из реализаций спецификации `JPA`, т.е. он умеет переводить `Java` объекты в записи реляционной таблицы, создавать запросы по записи, чтению и управлению данными.

`Spring Data JPA` - часть библиотеки `Spring`, которая предоставляет дополнительный уровень абстракции, чтобы сократить количество одинакового кода, например такого, как работа с `EntityManager`.

Суммируя написанное выше, подведём, что `Hibernate` это реализация `JPA` спецификации, в то время как `Spring Data JPA` предоставляет ещё один уровень абстракции, над `JPA`.

1. Для того, чтобы писать меньше кода, так как репозитории способны сгенерировать код, под необходимый запрос. Отпадает необходимость тащить тот же `EntityManager` и писать запросы вида:

   ```
   public List<Smth> findAll() {
      return session.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Smth a", Smth.class).getResultList();      
   }
   ```

   когда в репозитории этот же код выглядит следующим образом:

   ```
   public interface SmthRepository extends JpaRepository<Smth, Long> {
     List<Smth> findAll();
   }
   ```
2. `Spring` генерирует код на основе названия и сигнатуре методов интерфейсе, иногда ему можно помочь сгенерировать правильный запрос с помощью аннотации `@Query`.
3. Да, как подметил @Sergey Gornostaev, 1 и 3 вопросы одинаковые.
4. Как было сказано в ответе 2, генерация происходит по имени и сигнатуре метода.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ответ в третьем пункте.
2. Spring создаёт реализацию интерфейса на лету.
3. Да.
4. Ответ во втором пункте.

Стандартная матрёшка абстракций

```
Spring Data
     |
    JPA
     |
    JDBC
```

Каждый новый уровень скрывает (абстрагирует) детали низлежащего.